# Why does 'every node' not work inside a scope environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, scoping

I just tried the following and was suprised it didn't work:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  ... some commands

  \begin{scope}[very thick,
    every node=./style={circle, fill=white, minimum size=1.2mm, inner sep=0pt}
    ]

    \node {};
  \end{scope}

  ... other commands

\end{tikzpicture}
```

results in

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/every node./style' 
and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

How can I make `every node` available in a `scope` environment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a typo in the syntax. Compare your version with this one.

```
\begin{scope}[
  very thick,
  every node/.style={   % <<< here was your typo
    circle,
    fill=white,
    minimum size=1.2mm,
    inner sep=0pt
  }
]

  \node {};
\end{scope}
```

Comment: No reason for that. Typos occur in the best circles.

Comment: Apparently the `=` in `every node=/.style...` is ignored though. I didn't know that... Does anybody know why this happens? I can understand why they would not be allowed in the key tree, but stripped out alltogether seems a bit strange.